# Rails app with React front-end not showing up changes on production server

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I have made a web app using Rails 7.0.6 and I added a front end with React.
When I deployed my app the first time, everything gone well. Then I made some changes, I push them on github then I pull them on my server (NGINX ruby 1.22.1), I ran bundle install, npm install and db:migrate. But then changes made on my front-end did not appears. I know that my changes have been pull because my database has been modified, and the files on my server has changed. However nothing on my front-end changed... I have tried to touch the tmp/restart.txt file and to clear my cache but nothing worked...

Do you have any clue?

PS: I am running my app on jelastic cloud and I used esbuild as bundler for my assets

Comment: Running `npm install` is not enough for applying changes. You need to run `npm run build` or `npm start`, etc.

Comment: That's it... I had to run npm run build, then restart my server and the changes applied. Thank you !

Comment: Ok, glad to help. Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For React and many other single-page applications, your changes need to be compiled into a dist folder (in React, it's `build` folder) before they're served. Or, on local environment, you need to run `npm start` to start a local dev server.

Simply running `npm install` won't trigger these actions.

So, run `npm run build` and see if the changes are applied.